# FTPClient takes longer time to logout in java

Tags: java, ftp-client

My `FTPClient` code is working fine, but the only problem is when I call  `ftps.logout()` function it takes longer time to disconnect at least 5 - 10 mins and after that next line of code is executed.

Below is my code.

```
 try {
  FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient("SSL");  
  ftps.connect(hostname, port);
  returnCode = ftps.getReplyCode();
  if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(returnCode)) {
     throw new IOException("Could not connect");
  }
  boolean loggedIn = ftps.login(username, password);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    throw new IOException("Could not login");
  }
  ((FTPSClient) ftps).execPBSZ(0);
  ((FTPSClient) ftps).execPROT("P");
  ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();

  log("Connected and logged in.");

  // code to read ftp file goes here .............

  } catch (Exception e) {
    log(e.getMessage());
 }
 finally{
 if (ftps != null && ftps.isConnected()) {
     ftps.logout(); // after this line execution to next line comes after 5 - 10 mins
     log("Ftp Logged out");
     ftps.disconnect();
     log("ftp disconnected");

   }
}
```

Can someone please help me out what's wrong going on, why it take's longer time to logout ftp

I am using `FTPSClient` from `apache commons-net-3.1.jar`:

[image: File Zilla Server Configuration]

Thanks..

Comment: Why don't you call your logout method in an another thread ? So your code will work normally.

Comment: Are you using Java 7?

Comment: @akhil_mittal I am using Java 6

Comment: @SercanOzdemir but the same is working fine in other project.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I am getting this error in run method of thread Cannot ` refer to a non-final variable ftps inside an inner class defined in a different method` . `Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
          public void run() {
          ftps.logout();     
           }
                  
        });`

Comment: put "final" keyword to in front of your ftps variable.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir if put ftps.logout in spread Thread then I got this error `Connection is not open`, because ftps is already disconnected.

Comment: then everything is ok, just check if you are connected to ftp, if not do nothing, otherwise logout.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir what will happen if I disconnect and not logout out? will the instance of object will remain even after disconnect?

Comment: Instance will be collected by GC after a while, but your connection will stay for a while then it will timeout.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir Thank You for you time and effort.